# Spyder auto-indent stopped working

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, auto-indent

I have been using Anaconda/Spyder for years. Today auto-indent just stopped indenting after a "for" statement with a colon. I also tried it with absolutely no code above the for statement, so it isn't a syntax error in a previous line. Am I being dense?

Comment: have you tried restarting spyder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restore the default settings through terminal/CMD like so:

`spyder --reset`

Alternatively delete the `.spyder` folder, located in your users folder.

Comment: OK, that's got it. Tks.